# How to initialize declared istringstream with string?

Tags: c++, getline, istringstream

In C++, how do you initialize a declared istringstream with a string?

example.hpp

```
#include <sstream>
class example{
    private:
        istringstream _workingStream;
    public:
        example();
}
```

example.cpp

```
example::example(){
    this->_workingStream("exampletext");
}
```

Error

> error: no match for call to ‘(std::istringstream {aka std::basic_istringstream}) (const char [8])’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct a class member you need to use the [class member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).  Once you are inside the body of the constructor all class members have all be constructed and all you can do is assign to them.  To use the member initialization list you need to change the constructor to

```
example::example() : _workingStream("exampletext") {}
```

Comment: Found it can also be done in the constructor with `this->_workingStream.str("exampletext");`

Comment: @Eugene - generally speaking, its better to initialise class members in the initialiser list than the constructor body, if possible.    Even if you don't, the object will need to be initialised before you can set it in the constructor body, so better to avoid a "initialise then reset" cycle.